# How to make the snacks in my game appear in random colors?

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried several things, but so far have only managed a few shades of blue, and occasionally black snacks

I've tried:

```py
def main():
    global width, rows, s, snack
    width = 600
    rows = 40
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake((50,205,50), (10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(randint(0,255)))
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(randint(0,255)))
```

but cannot do 3 parameters, so only got a few shades of blue.

```py
def main():
    global width, rows, s, snack
    width = 600
    rows = 40
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake((50,205,50), (10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(255,215,0))
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(255,215,0))
```

I'm wanting to get a different color each time a snack appears, except for the (255,0,0), as that is the color for my background, but so far have only been able to get shades of blue, with the occasional black snack.

Comment: I'd recommend pre-defining a set of colors that you want to use. That way you can control the contrast between those colors and the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @njzx2 said in the comments, it's better to make a set of predefined colors and pick one randomly from this set. Even if you exclude the background color, you may get by chance a color very close to it, which will be hardly seen by the human eye.

Add to your main function, or wherever is best in your case, a set of colors:

```
#colors here are black, white, green and blue, just an example, set them on your own accord
cubecolors = ((0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255))
```

Then to pick randomly one of them when creating the snack, do:

```
snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=random.choice(cubecolor))
```

Remember to `import random` module.

Note that I used the term *set*, but `cubecolor` actually is not a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set), is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#tuple). `random.choice` does not work with a `set`.

Answer (score 1):

You want a tuple with 3 entries (one for each RBG value: red, green, blue). The solution you have in the first block only has one value. You instead want:

```
color = (randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
```

To ensure that this color is not the background color, I would define a function which returns a random color that is not the background color:

```
def randomNonBackgroundColor():
    color = (randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
    if color == (255, 0, 0):
        return getRandomNonBackgroundColor()
    else:
        return color
```

Then,

```
def main():
    global width, rows, s, snack
    width = 600
    rows = 40
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake((50,205,50), (10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=randomNonBackgroundColor())
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=randomNonBackgroundColor())
```